# VKontakte photo uploads: `aid undefined`

Tags: node.js, api, rest, vk

Following the instructions on http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-17680044&p=Uploading_Files_to_the_VK_Server_Procedure, I get an error on the first step:

```
    error: {
        error_code: 100,
        error_msg: 'One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: aid undefined',
        request_params: [
            { key: 'oauth', value: '1' },
            { key: 'method', value: 'photos.getUploadServer' },
            { key: 'v', value: '5.2' },
            { key: 'access_token', value: 'REDACTED' },
            { key: 'aid', value: '186300854' },
            { key: 'owner_id', value: '240220170' }
        ]
    }
```

However, the `aid` (album ID) parameter is clearly specified.

As seen, I've tried specifying `owner_id` in addition to `aid`, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Answer seems to be that the album ID parameter is now called `album_id`, and not `aid` (despite the English docs and error messages refer to `aid`).